# Popular escape condition for calculating Mandelbrot Set, $|z|>2$, is incomplete?

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-dynamics

The Mandelbrot set is often rendered by calculating whether a point, a complex number $c$, diverges under the iterated function $z_{n+1}=z^2_n+c$, where $z_0=0$ and $c$ is the point being tested.

Those points which diverge under that iteration are designated as being outside the Mandelbrot set.

As a test for divergence, many simple algorithms check to see if $|z_n|$ grows larger than 2.

I tried to find the origin of the very common computational test, and finally a derivation in *Chaos and Fractals: New Frontiers of Science by Peitgen, Jurgens and Saupe, 2004 [ISBN-13 : 978-0387202297]*.

**Question:** My interpretation is that **two, not one,** conditions need to be met for divergence. **Am I correct?** Most software implementations only use of the two conditions.

See below for derivation, based on that source.

---

Start with triangle inequality $|a+b|\leq|a|+|b|$, with $a=z^{2}+c$ and $b=-
c$, noting also $|-c|=|c|$,

$$|z^{2}+c-c|\leq|z^{2}+c|+|c|$$

We're interested in $|z^2+c|$, so isolate it

$$|z^{2}+c|\geq|z^{2}|-|c|$$

Also, $|z^{2}|$ is the same as $|z|^{2}$ so we have

$$|z^{2}+c|\geq|z|^{2}-|c|$$

**Condition 1:** if we say that $|z|$ is bigger than $|c|$, that would mean

$$|z|^{2}-|c|>|z|^{2}-|z|$$

Which means we can also say,

$$|z^{2}+c|>|z|^{2}-|z|$$

Which can be factorised as

$$|z^{2}+c|>|z|\left(|z|-1\right)$$

If $z_{n}$ is the $n^{th}$ point in an orbit, then the next point in the orbit is $z_{n+1}=z_{n}^{2}+c$. We can rewrite the above expression as a ratio,

$$\frac{|z_{n+1}|}{|z_{n}|}>|z_{n}|-1$$

**Condition 2:** If we now also say that $|z|$ is greater than 2, we have $|z|-1>1$. So we finally have

$$\frac{|z_{n+1}|}{|z_{n}|}>1$$

This is telling us that $|z_{n+1}|$ is always greater than $|z_{n}|$, that is we have divergence, as long as:

- $|z|>|c|$, and
- $|z|>2$

So we've shown that if the above **two** conditions are true, then the orbit of a point will escape.

---

**Thoughts**

My thinking is that every software-implemented algorithm I have seen only implements the test $|z|>2$ because $|c|$ for most of the region of interest is less than 2. Is this correct?

The region of interest is the rectangle with corners $-2.25+1.5i$ and $0.75-1.5i$, and the largest $|c|$ here is about 2.7.

Comment: Is it true that if $|c|>2$ then $|z_n| \to\infty$?  If so, then the classic divergence criterion "$\exists n, |z_n|>2$" is correct.

Comment: Misha's response completely answers your question. It might be worth pointing out that, if you want to generate the Julia set of $f_c(z)=z^2+c$, then you certainly do need to take both conditions into account. The distinction is that, for the Mandelbrot set, you always start the iteration from zero so that $z_1=c$ and you've already satisfied $|z_1|\geq|c|$ (which is all you really need). For Julia sets, you fix $c$ and start with different $z_0$ values. You no longer have $z_1\geq|c|$ and, in fact, there are values of $c$ with Julia sets that extend outside the disk of radius 2.

Comment: @MarkMcClure - a very useful addition to the question, thank you. Out of interest, the few software implementations I've seen don't check both conditions ... is there a mathematically sound explanation why one condition is "good enough"?

Comment: If you're generating an image of a Julia set for $z^2+c$, then you really need both conditions. If $c<-2$, for example, there is a real fixed point larger than 2 that will be misclassified.  There are also lots of points inside the disk of radius 2 that land on that fixed point after just a few iterations that will also be misclassified. Of course, this kind of Julia set is quite sparse so that this detail is easy to miss.

Comment: quick query @MarkMcClure - I noted you said $z_1 = c$ means you've satisfied $|z_1|\geq |c|$. Surely wee want $|z_1| > |c|$ not $\geq$ because that is what leads to the ratio $z_{n+1}/z_n > 1$. If we had $z_{n+1}/z_n > 1$, that would not always mean divergence. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: The correct divergence criterion is, if $|z_k|>2$ and $|z_k| \geq |c|$ for some $k$, then the orbit diverges. For then,
$$\begin{align}|z_{k+1}| &= |z_k^2+c| \geq |z_k|^2 - |c| \\ &\geq |z_k|^2 - |z_k| = |z_k|(|z_k| - 1) = \lambda |z_k|,\end{align}$$
where $\lambda > 1$. In particular, we don't need strict inequality when comparing against $|c|$, though we do need it when comparing against $2$.

Comment: just to say that I've spent a week since the original comment by @MarkMcClure reading pseudocode, wikis including wikipedia's pseudocode, online lecture notes by proper academics at universities, even published textbooks, and all of them use the single escape condition for Julia Sets, $|z|>2$ ... it seems the misunderstanding is very prevalent

Comment: Taking a quick look at [Wikipedia's page on Julia sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set), I see that they assume an escape radius $R$ satisfying $R^2-R>|c|$ and they note the fact that $R=2$ is sufficient when $|c|\leq2$. Clearly, the issue has been considered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mandelbrot set only contains points $c$ with $|c| \le 2$.

To see this, let's go from $z_0 = 0$ to $z_1 = c$ to $z_2 = c^2+c$. If $|c| > 2$, then $|c^2| = |c|^2 > 2|c|$, which means that $$|z_2| = |c^2+c| \ge |c^2| - |c| > |c|.$$ So for $z_2$, *both* of your conditions for divergence are satisfied, which means that $c$ is not in the Mandelbrot set.

---

As a result, though the proof of divergence in the question logically requires both $|z_n| > 2$ and $|z_n| > |c|$ to work, we can dispense with the second condition: for all points $c$ which possibly *could* be in the Mandelbrot set, the first condition implies the second.

Comment: excellent answer - very clear