# Why is the triangle inequality at the heart of so many proofs in different fields of mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, intuition, triangle-inequality

**Question:** Why is the triangle inequality at the heart of so many proofs?

**Discussion**

In many areas of mathematics, from complex analysis to discrete number theory, and even [chaos theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4803377/popular-escape-condition-for-calculating-mandelbrot-set-z2-is-incomplete), many theorems and smaller lemmas make use of the triangle inequality as part of, or the foundation of, their proof.

$$|a+b|\leq|a|+|b|$$

The school-level understanding of this inequality is that "the most direct path between two points is the shortest" doesn't quite give enough insight into the disproportionate power of the inequality.

I'm not an expert (self-teaching) but I feel a deeper insight might have something to do with the geometry of multi-dimensional objects which provides sufficient constraint to be useful for proving such identities.

**Request:** I would prefer answers to be accessible to non-experts who are not familiar with terminology like manifolds, metric spaces and fields.

Comment: You use it to prove that if a is close to b and b is close to c, then a is close to c. The triangle inequality is the foundation behind approximation arguments, which are used to simplify analysis and for real world application.

Comment: The triangle inequality is one of only three axioms for a metric or normed space, and probably the most interesting one. Almost anything going on in any of these spaces depends on the triangle inequality. Otherwise, you are basically doing set theory or linear algebra.

Comment: It's based on a triangle. In any space, if you have three line segments, when can you make a triangle out of them? Are there cases where you can't make a triangle? Why not? What fails?

Comment: Since we are forbidden to say "metric spaces", that school level phrase is really it.

Comment: If you want more then what I would suggest is to look into how the triangle inequality is *applied* in elementary mathematics. Perhaps if you did more research into how it is applied, there could be a more focussed question to be asked. Meanwhile, I am voting to close.